# NGINX deny access to remnant .htaccess files for ALL server blocks globally

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

i'm switching from apache to nginx and i am not yet ready to remove apache files such as .htaccess

therefore i want to deny access to them.

i know this is how:
`location ~ /\.ht { deny  all; }`

BUT how to do it GLOBALLY? that is, for ALL server blocks (vhosts) at once.

i'm hoping to have it as a single directive under the main `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` like so:

```
http {
    # STUFF

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;

        # STUFF
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

i tried the configuration above and reloaded nginx, but i am still able to download .htaccess file

Comment: after more research, i'm beginning to believe the answer is having a default.conf and loading that inside each server block... which is undesirable... but if that's the way it's done...

Answer (score 1):

after researching and experimenting...

yes... the only apparent way is to have an included conf file in each and every server block.

INCLUDED CONF FILE CONTENTS (potentially located at /etc/nginx/default.d/default.conf... up to you)

```
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}
```

ENABLED SITE CONF FILE (potentially located at /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.com.conf)

```
server {
    # STUFF
    include /path/to/included/file.conf
    # (example) include /etc/nginx/default.d/default.conf
}
```

it's not as desirable to me, but it is efficient and logical

all the directives in "default.conf" should be coded just like any include (as if it is inline with the content)

in other words... you wouldn't use server {...} in the content of default.conf since it's being included inside a server block already